# Structures Having Eigen Members in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, eigen

The Eigen documentation mentions that structures having fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types can cause problems with allocation. They mention:

> If you're compiling in [c++17] mode only with a sufficiently recent compiler (e.g., GCC>=7, clang>=5, MSVC>=19.12), then everything is taken care by the compiler and you can stop reading.

Does it mean that the problem is present when compiling with [c++20], since they stress [c++17] mode only? Or is the problem solved for any compiler since [c++17]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is based on [P0035R4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html) (*Dynamic memory allocation for over-aligned data*) which was *introduced* in C++17, which means the statement arguably holds also for C++20. However, there seem to be some issues and pitfalls with this statement, even if following the advice of the Eigen guidelines, e.g. as highlighted in [PointCloudLibrary
/
pcl / issue #4258](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/4258).

Comment: Interesting, if I understand correctly you mean that one should always add the macro EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW, regardless of the compiler and the c++ version used, correct?

Comment: @marco ```EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW``` is empty for c++17, as the documentation reports.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty clear: only compiling in `c++17` mode with a recent compiler (it's an AND) protects you from the alignment issues. So, using a more recent compiler but failing to set `-std=c++17` exposes you to the issue. The solution, as suggested in the documentation, is to modify the code and take advantage of the `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` macro (which is empty for `c++17`)

Alternatively, the documentation proposes other, less intrusive solutions: [here.](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html#StructHavingEigenMembers_othersolutions)

Comment: I understand that I need a recent compiler. My question is if only c++17 solves the problem or it works with c++20 as well. So if I understand correctly you say that using a recently compiler and compiling with c++20 exposes me to that issue. Correct?

Comment: @marco that's how I interpret the documentation, yes.